# SSL Certificate added to website causing tabs, accordion and menu drop-downs to stop working

Tags: ssl, tabs, accordion

I have recently added a SSL Certificate to my website but it’s causing issues with some functionality no longer working when the site is accessed with https.  The tabs, accordion and menu doesn’t work on the https version on the below links for example.

http://waflfootyfacts.net/player/stats.php?PlayerID=4764

https://waflfootyfacts.net/player/stats.php?PlayerID=4764

Any idea where I can start looking at the fix?  Is this a common thing that can happen with SSL?

I am not a web developer and had an old work mate help me with the site and I’ve been self-taught since and this has stumped me.

I am using metro-bootstrap css and am using relative paths throughout the site except on the header where I am using absolute paths

Comment: Please have a look at the developer tools inside the browser. Even the `http://` version shows lots of errors where it cannot include content since it simply does not exist at this path at the server. The `https://` version additionally shows content blocked to including `http://` inside `https://` (mixed content), specifically `metro.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the issue - I had a JS loader that was loading http script